# Flutter - how to support all languages in an app, eg include all of kMaterialSupportedLanguages in supportedLocales?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization, flutter-localizations

Instead of specifying locales one by one in the MaterialApp supportedLocales entry, https://docs.flutter.dev/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#specifying-supportedlocales
could we support every possible locale from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/kMaterialSupportedLanguages.html?
Would it be a simple map from kMaterialSupportedLanguages to supportedlocales format?